# Javascript function doesn't return anything

Tags: javascript, function

My javascript function doesn't return anything. I really don't get it. Is it a problem of variable scope?

```
function getLanguage(){
    navigator.globalization.getLocaleName(
        function(locale){
            var lan = locale.value;
        },
        function(){
            var lan = null;
        }
    );
    return lan;
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Yes, scope is the issue. Define `lan` before `navigator.globalization.getLocaleName`

Comment: It is returning `lan`; did you check to see what its value is?

Comment: If you want to avoid callback-soup use `Promises`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a duplicate of the old [asynchronicity problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron), but there's a second issue as well -- scope.

First of all, scope. The `lan` variable is defined inside the internal function, and so cannot be seen from outside.

```
function getLanguage(){
    var lan;
    navigator.globalization.getLocaleName(
        function(locale){
            lan = locale.value;
        },
        function(){
            lan = null;
        }
    );
    return lan;
}
```

That was easy. But it still won't work, due to asynchronity. You have to set up your function to use a callback instead:

```
function getLanguage(callback){
    navigator.globalization.getLocaleName(
        function(locale){
            callback(locale.value);
        },
        function(){
            callback(null);
        }
    );
}
```

Also, by now, we don't even need the variable, so i got rid of it.

Then, you call it as:

```
getLanguage(function(lan){
    // something with lan here
});
```